# Don't want to select date react-native-calendars Agenda

Tags: react-native, react-native-calendars

native app and using Agenda of react-native calendars. I am using knob to open agenda as shown in the gif https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wix/react-native-calendars/master/demo/agenda.gif but if user don't want to select or want to cancel this operation what they will do. I want knob to close that agenda. Or something to cancel operation please help.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Modal component for that purpose. Render Calendar inside Modal where you can add a cancel button.